# How do I access query parameters in the request content body in javascript?

Tags: javascript, post, request

If I use a GET to request a page, then I can access any query parameters from javascript using window.location.search.  Is there a similar way to access query parameters which are in the request content body rather than the request location, when the page is a result of a POST?

Answer (score 2):

Because the data is being handled on the server side, the client (where JS lives) has no access to these variables.